# Android why focus first element?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-edittext, focus

Android is focused first focusable element when Activity startup
This also happens when the layout changes

So if device use EditText when SoftInputMode is resize, device will lose focus as layout changes

However, you can not use adjustPan because it requires the resize property.

Also, you can not use focusable and focusableInTouchMode because you must maintain focus when the layout changes.

Is there any way to specify the first focus?
Or can i keep focus when the layout changes?

Answer (score 0):

You can set focus by using `requestFocus()` method on the element you want to, for example

```
 final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
 textView.requestFocus();
```

Comment: I tried this method, but I could specify focus, but I could not arbitrarily set focus by the Android system when the layout changed. I could not keep focus.

Comment: Explain me what exactly you want to do,Will try to solve your problem.

Comment: I can not use EditText because there is a problem that the focus changes to the first element when the layout is changed when the keyboard appears by touching EditText.

Comment: add this line in EditText in Xml file  android:focusable="false"

Comment: However, I can not use EditText if focusable is false.

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText firsteditText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.first); 
firsteditText.requestFocus();
```

Comment: if you want to focus using xml then use <EditText...>
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

Comment: Please avoid posting code-only answers. Please explain why this will help.

Comment: Request focus is used to set automatically keypad function on edittext box so just after activity starts it will automatically select defined Requestfocus editText and open keypad so application user can directly insert data into editText box.